# How can I determine how much storage is required for a specific podcast?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I want to download some podcasts for offline listening/viewing, how can I determine how much storage they will take on my device before downloading them?

Comment: Specify device, Mac, iOS, Watch, etc. Also in my experience most podcast providers don't specify size only length, you may have to look for a podcast player that gives you that info. The only way I have ever found was to download it and get info on the file in the Finder.

Comment: Any device! Open to third-party providers - I personally use the Apple Podcasts app. Yea I can see the size after the download, wanted it before.

Comment: Indeed and I use overcast and there is no indication of the size there at all, nor in iTunes. Perhaps the Google Play store podcasts section? Dunno, never used them.